# Editing log messages - LogEventFactory vs RewriteAppender

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j2

The application that I work on has to mask some sensitive data in logs, so I have to somehow edit them. However it also stores some variables in `ThreadLocal` and puts them in logs. Normally, I would use `PatternLayout` in appender to put them into logged string. Unfortunately, if the logging is being performed asynchronous, loggers simply can't access `ThreadLocal` variables.

I have made a workaround for that problem, using `LogEventFactory`. I pass a layout to logger as a property in its declaration in log4j2.xml and then perform formatting in my custom event factory. It looks like that:

```
<AsyncLogger name="AsyncLogger">
    <Property name="layout" value="%d %x{var1} %x{var2} %x{var3}/>
    <AppenderRef="ref"/>
<AsyncLogger/>
```

It doesn't seem to be an elegant solution. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Look [here](https://objectpartners.com/2017/09/26/masking-sensitive-data-in-log4j-2/) and [here](https://gomtiprabha.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/masking-sensitive-info-or-data-in-logs/) for some solutions on this.